# Iterating through folder for files and adding up values within a column?

Tags: python

I have multiple files with data written in two column looks like:

```
asp 1.88
gln 3.10
arg 0.99
his 1.11
```

and

```
asp 0.99
gln 1.11
arg 0.08
his 0.01
```

and so on.

What I want to do is add them up and write to a new file like this:

```
asp 2.87
gln 4.21
arg 1.07
his 1.12
```

I was trying by importing `Counter` but it is not doing well. I also tried like this:

```
inp = ('c"/users/ansm/desktop/xx.txt','r').read().strip().split('\n')
inp2 = ('c"/users/ansm/desktop/xyz.txt','r').read().strip().split('\n')
c = Counter(inp)
d = Counter(inp2)
print c+d
```

but this code doesn't add up the values.

Is there any other way to do it without using `Counter`?
I was using `glob.iglob` to iterate throughout the folder for files with `.txt` format and then want to process them to get above mentioned result. Will using `Counter` be the most efficient way to do it or would some other way even better?

Comment: paste your `inp` and `inpu2` output(lists) in question.

Comment: Are the two files guaranteed to have the same (alphabetical) entries, in the same order? Or do you need to match them?

Comment: yeah! order for each file is same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the Counters using this construct:

```
c = Counter(dict((x.split()[0], float(x.split()[1])) for x in inp))
d = Counter(dict((x.split()[0], float(x.split()[1])) for x in inp2))
```

The result `c+d` will be:

```
Counter({'gln': 4.21, 'asp': 2.87, 'his': 1.12, 'arg': 1.07})
```

**EDIT** for many files:

```
s = Counter()
for filename in glob.iglob('*.txt'):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            k, v = line.split()
            s[k] += float(v)
print s
with open('sum.txt', 'w') as f:
    for k, v in sorted(s.iteritems()):
        f.write('{0} {1}\n'.format(k, v))
```

Comment: but how this method could be implied if I want to perform this operation for n number of files ?

Comment: Use a base counter: `sum = Counter()`, then in your loop create a new counter for the file and `sum += filecount` will sum them all.

Comment: @eumiro a little help please... how could i write this c+d into a file.

Comment: @eumiro can you say me any good tutorial page for Counter operation...oh! by the way, thanx for your help..

Comment: @Ovisek - there is not much to learn about Counter: http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 1):

How about using defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import glob

d = defaultdict(float)

for filename in glob.iglob('*.txt'):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            k,v = f.split(" ")
            d[k] += float(v)

with open("output.txt", "w") as out:
    for k, v in d.iteritems:
        out.write("%s %f\n" % (k,v))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach (w/o using `Counter` as requested):

```
with open('xx.txt') as f1, open('xyz.txt') as f2, open('result.txt', 'w') as outf:
    for line1 in f1:
        for line2 in f2:
            count = float(line1.split()[-1]) + float(line2.split()[-1])
            outf.write('{:s} {:.2f}\n'.format(line2.split()[0], count))
```

and `result.txt` contains:

```
asp 2.87
gln 2.99
arg 1.96
his 1.89
```

This assumes the data contain the same keys and that they are in the same order.

Using the `with` construct will automatically close the 3 files for you when you are done or if an exception occurs.

Comment: This assumes that the files a) always contain the exact same keys and b) always in the same order. Not sure if that is a correct assumption. Also, your example output looks incorrect (repeating 'asp').

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good point, I'll state my assumptions explicitly. I'll fix the other problem and update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add each of the elements in both counters as follows, because the original counters are storing strings and not numbers for their values (notice the `float()` conversion):

```
r = Counter(c)
for k, v in d.items():
    r[k] += float(v)
```

Now the added values are in `r`. A simpler approach would be to perform the conversion directly when creating `c` and `d`:

```
c = Counter((p[0], float(p[1])) for p in map(lambda s: s.split(), inp))
d = Counter((p[0], float(p[1])) for p in map(lambda s: s.split(), inp2))
```

Now this will work as intended:

```
c + d
> Counter({'gln': 4.21, 'asp': 2.87, 'his': 1.12, 'arg': 1.07})
```

Also be aware that the way you're reading the files is not the safest: you open but never close them, a better approach would be to use `with open`, something like this:

```
inp = []
with open('c:/users/ansm/desktop/xx.txt', 'r') as input:
    for line in input:
        inp.append(line.strip())
```

Comment: You may want to read the Counter documentation; values default to 0 if the key was not present, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters there, I simplified it as suggested